# Why do we need a neshama yesera?

Tags: shabbat, soul

On shabbos we get an additional soul (tannis 27b) - what is the utility of this soul? Is it the same one every week? Why would we need an extra soul?

Comment: Why do we need the first soul?

Comment: @DoubleAA to animate our flesh (per Genesis) but we seem to do pretty well with just one the rest of the week

Comment: @DoubleAA I think I remember reading in Michtav MeEliyahu that he heard from his father that it's possible to lose your soul. (I don't remember exactly where and I don't have the book in front of me, but I am pretty confident that it's in volume 1, madur ri'shon.)

Comment: @DoubleAA -- http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @DoubleAA Page 72. I just looked at it in my shul's library.

Comment: @ba Very interesting. What happens to people without souls?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't remember what he writes on the spot (I left it at the library and didn't go over it past seeing the page number), but I do remember he says a few times (e.g. at the beginning of madur sheni on page 100-something concerning a Ben Sorer UMoreh, and a little more explicitly some time early in madur ri'shon though I unfortunately don't currently have a more exact citation than that) that some people are like dummies completely controlled by the sitra achara in order to show that it's possible for a wicked person to seem to enjoy life. (I don't remember the rest exactly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

neshama yeterah doesn't literally mean "an extra soul", it means "extra soul" as if the amount of soul that you have is continuous.  the conceptualization is for example that you have less soul when you are tired or angry and more soul when you are at rest.  see footnote 5 on neshama yeterah in the tenth chapter of The Sabbath by Heschel [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31h0C.png).

Comment: Hebrew doesn't have a word for the indefinite article, so I'm not sure your diyuk is at all meaningful.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I read this as more an assertion than a diyuk.

Comment: it is a diyuk and the point is that yeterah doesn't only mean "another", it also means "more"

Answer (score 6):

Rashi in [Maseches Beitza 16a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=8&daf=16&format=pdf) writes that the *neshama yesera* is:

> רוחב לב למנוחה ולשמחה ולהיות פתוח לרוחה ויאכל וישתה ואין נפשו קצה עליו

This very roughly means that it expands his heart so that he has a greater capacity for rest and joy and is able to eat and drink more without overdoing it.

Comment: +1, See Likkutey Sichos ([vol. 31 pg. 191](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14954&st=&pgnum=204)) where the Lubavitcher Rebbe explains that there are two distinct explanations for the concept of "neshama yesera", that of the revealed parts of Torah, and that of the hidden parts. The Rashi above is consistent with the answer according to the revealed parts, while [my answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22808/1535) tries to explain the esoteric meaning.

Comment: No calories on Shabbos, right?

Comment: "[W]ithout overdoing it" to me means "without eating exceedingly much" whereas "ואין נפשו קצה עליו" to me means "without becoming disgusted [by the food]".

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Shnuer Zalman of Liadi explains the idea of the *Neshama Yesera* in Torah Ohr ([Parshas Vayakel pg. 87](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16069&st=&pgnum=180)). The discourse is elucidated in the [Chassidus Mevue'res series](http://store.chassidus.com/item_detail.php?item_id=24528)  (Shabbos pg. 23), and is adapted in English [here](http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380628/jewish/Our-Super-Shabbat-Soul.htm).

The basic explanation is as follows: Midrash Rabba writes that the soul is called by five names: Nefesh, Ruach, Neshama, Chaya, and Yechida. These names refer to five different levels and types of revelation within the soul of a person, with the highest level being the Yechida. This level of the soul is totally united with G-d. With the coming of Shabbos, this deepest level of a person's soul, the Yechida, is revealed within the person. This is the Additional Soul we are given on Shabbos.

It is not felt as an increase in physical life, but rather, an increase in the spiritual life force of a person: There are two types of love for G-d; one type of love is born out of contemplation of the greatness and oneness of G-d. The second is a love that is not born out of contemplation and intellect. Rather, it is a love for G-d that transcends intellect. This deep and unbounded love for G-d is the experience of our Additional Soul on Shabbos.